# Does AWS WAF support classic ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-elb, amazon-waf

if we try to enable WAF in Classic ELB i am unable to create may i know way to implement it so it will be help full for us to set a layer of security in the infra

Answer (score 7):

To use WAF two options:

1. Test your application with ALB. If successfully tested, migrate your application from the current Classic ELB to ALB and deploy WAF
2. If you do not want to do option 1, you can look at deploying a CloudFront distribution, set your ELB as the origin of the distribution and deploy WAF in front of the CloudFront distribution